# Pending upgrade of Eclipse Gradle IDE from v3.6.4 to v3.7.0 fails with missing dependencies

Tags: eclipse, gradle

In my Eclipse Luna instance on Win7, I have version 3.6.4 of the SpringSource Gradle IDE plugin, along with other plugins in the SpringSource suite.

A couple of days ago when I checked for new updates, I saw that it was offering version 3.7.0 of this plugin.  I found this a little surprising, as I thought this plugin was going to be sunsetted as the BuildShip plugin gains functionality (which seems like it's going to take a while).  Nevertheless, if there's an update, I wanted to get it.  I tried searching for release notes for this update, but I couldn't find anything.

When I tried installing the update, it eventually failed with this:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core,3.7.0.201506251228-RELEASE
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.toolingapi,3.7.0.201506251228-RELEASE
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui,3.7.0.201506251228-RELEASE
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui.taskview,3.7.0.201506251228-RELEASE
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.feature,3.7.0.201506251228-RELEASE
```

Since the first time this failed a few days ago, I've tried several times, all with the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to resolve this.  It appears that Eclipse's cache of what's on update sites was wrong, and it wasn't checking.  I discovered that just clicking "Reload" on the associated update site fixed this, so I was able to update successfully.

I posted [this github issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/eclipse-integration-gradle/issues/92) about this, and the author recommended that solution.